# Downloading content with file_get_contents then deleting after

Tags: php

Currently I found this site for music related tools that is very handy it offers a mirror for file hosts, and I am trying to download some MP3 with file_get_contents and delete it afterwards pushed to this file host mirror.

current code have is this..

```
$mp3 = 'http://www.example.com/song.mp3';
$name = 'song';
file_put_contents('tmp/'.$name.'.mp3',file_get_contents($mp3));
```

Which will store the MP3 we're trying to gather, but after it saves this information I want it to run through the function on this file mirror we found [API](https://www.filemack.com/en/api) then delete the MP3 file from our tmp directory afterwards.

the site is filemack

Comment: is your question how to delete the file? or how to use the filemack API?

Comment: @mistermartin I want to push my MP3 to filemack API then delete after my  server push it file but not understanding well how to do this.. am only css and html developer main thing..

Comment: the link you provided gives an example how to upload the file. PHP uses [`unlink`](http://php.net/unlink) to delete files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
include('filemack.class.php');

// set path to temp directory
$temp_directory = dirname(__FILE__).'/tmp';

// set direct url to mp3
$mp3_url = 'https://www.filemack.com/embed/stream-demo.mp3';

// set name of mp3
$name = 'song';

// download file to temp directory
file_put_contents($temp_directory.'/'.$name.'.mp3',file_get_contents($mp3_url));

## start the filemack class
$filemack = new filemack;

## set your api key
$filemack->api_key = 'YOUR_API_KEY';

## set your api secret
$filemack->api_secret = 'YOUR_API_SECRET';

## enable individual hosts
$filemack->clicknupload = 1;
$filemack->dopefile = 1;

## or enable all of them    
$filemack->all();

## change embed color 1
$filemack->embed_color_1 = '375a7f';

## change embed color 2
$filemack->embed_color_2 = 'ffffff';

## upload the file
#$links = $filemack->upload($temp_directory.'/'.$name.'.mp3');

## upload the file with new filename
$links = $filemack->upload($temp_directory.'/'.$name.'.mp3',$name.'.mp3');

// file has been pushed to filemack so delete now
unlink($temp_directory.'/'.$name.'.mp3');

## links variable will be an array
Array
(
    [success] => 1
    [embed] => <iframe src="https://www.filemack.com/embed/YdugtL8sSzV5?c1=375a7f&c2=ffffff" frameborder="0" scrolling="none" width="100%" height="64"></iframe>
    [links] => Array
        (
        [filemack] => https://www.filemack.com/YdugtL8sSzV5
        [clicknupload] => https://www.filemack.com/cu_tQwdzijxCJpmOIqd
        [zippyshare] => https://www.filemack.com/zs_fL6CxCymd7EUe9Qh
        [dopefile] => https://www.filemack.com/df_rPNgoMH7pznIK6rq
        [affix] => https://www.filemack.com/af_c54jPe26dfcEc30a
        [tusfiles] => https://www.filemack.com/tf_RGtEhDrnlTMHsSKO
        [suprafiles] => https://www.filemack.com/sf_vm4g0FuRwXlxbBsP
    )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`unlink()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php):

```
unlink('tmp/'.$name.'.mp3');
```